# Can upload image with Assets, but image does not "stick" to entry

Tags: assets, database

I can upload an image to my Asset field(s) and publish the entry. However, here are the weird issues I'm experiencing:

1. The Asset field is blank when re-editing the published entry, (but...)
2. The original, uploaded image is available in the template
3. Trying to publish the entry where the Asset field appears blank throws a "Field is required" error as if the field contains no data

Ideas?

- Assets — 2.1.4
- ExpressionEngine — 2.5.5

Comment: Update: No errors in console

Comment: Hey Aaron, are you seeing any JS errors when selecting Assets? Do you have anything like Publisher or Better Workflow installed?

Comment: Thanks for the help, Brandon! No Publisher, Better Workflow, or anything of the like. Also, no JS errors when selecting and adding Assets. I only got a message of `Double-instantiating a select on an element` in `garnish-0.1.min.js:18`. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pixel and Tonic graciously made a ticket out of this request and cleared this issue up. (Thanks, guys!)

Here's what Andris had to say:

> You have set your upload folder paths to be relative, however when you
>   access the CP from the address admin.php, those paths turn out to be
>   incorrect.
>
> For them to work correctly, you must access the CP using the system
>   folder in path - for example -
>   http://domain.com/system/index.php?D=cp&C=content_publish&M=entry_form&channel_id=1&entry_id=1
>
> In Assets file manager everything was loading fine, because everything
>   there is loaded via Ajax and Ajax requests are routed via front-end
>   due to EE's design. Assets compensates for those requests, if they are
>   made this way.

I was accessing the control panel from `domain.com/admin.php` with relative upload paths and I needed to access the control panel from `domain.com/system/` for those paths to work.

Hope that helps anyone else with this issue!